# display overlapping chat history ASP.NET Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display chat history in a Razor View Page.I have a method that get's specified messages sent **to** user **A** from **user B**. and another method that gets  those for User B.I have this viewModel:

```
 public class SentReceivedMessagesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<PrivateMessage> IncomingMessages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PrivateMessage> OutGoingMessages { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }


}
```

And this Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Conversations(Guid targetId)
    {
        var myGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(this.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
        var incomingchats = db.IncomingHistoryFromUserId(targetId, myGuid);
        var outgoingchats = db.OutgoingHistoryToUserId(myGuid, targetId);
        var model = new SentReceivedMessagesViewModel
          {
              IncomingMessages=incomingchats,
              OutGoingMessages=outgoingchats,
          };
        return PartialView("Conversation",model);
    }
```

Dilemma is How do I organize the **View** so that I have a Facebook like **chat history** showing sent/received in overlapping pane? Any tutorials or demos?

Comment: +1 for well worded and good question, favourited for further use, also, what does it currently do? if anything? we know what you want but we dont know what youre getting and thats a really helpful step!

Comment: Currently It displays all incoming messages first, then outgoing and vice versa.But I want that ** href click**("chat history"). get send/receive in  facebook style paged view.I guess this provides useful lead

Comment: currently you have all sent messages in one list, and all recieved messages in another? you want to display them alternately but they come in in blocks currently? youll want to make a third list probably, and enter the data from the frist and second ones, hopefully you have some sort of time stamp property from each message (as maybe one person sends 2 messages before one is sent back) then use the time stamps of the messages from each list to enter the data into the third list based on the order of the time stamps, then just display the third list, i guess that might work in theory

Comment: where your var model would be the third list, and you can still return partialview of model

Comment: Giving that a shot and will update you, thanks though.